# MS Access SQL query return only actionable items

Tags: sql, ms-access

What MS Access SQL code (in a query [not VBA]) can I use to return only the row that actually has the "Action" populated ***for each loan number***
- or - if "Action" is not populated ***for that loan***, then return that row.
Highlighted rows below should result.  Thank you.

[image: Sample Data Set]

Comment: The result will be one row per loan #.  No loss of loan #s.

Comment: You say "one row per loan", but some of the loans have two yellow rows.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I noticed that afterwards.  I hesitated to add the additional condition.  A comment with a value other than zero trumps a comment with zero value.

Comment: What's wrong with `select loan, max(action) group by loan` ?

Comment: Corion, That actually worked really well.  Thank you for the effort.
~ Orlando